# Summary task (father) shows more work time as compared to the sum of sub tasks (children)

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2010

As displayed in the Microsoft project 2010 screenshot below, why the summary task (Create DSfile>) has 52hrs work whereas the sum of 2 child tasks is just 12h?

[image]

Solved: **Check to make sure that none of your summary tasks have resources assigned**

Comment: Can you confirm what the headings are for each column? Does the error show up only the one time in your Gantt?

Comment: What version of MS Project are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can happen when your summary tasks (or any children summary) tasks have resources assigned.  It can also happen when a child task is external, e.g. located in an external project file.

So, check to make sure that none of your summary tasks have resources assigned, and none of the have predecessors or successors assigned.  If your project file has subprojects, or external dependencies, open up all of the files in the set so MS Project can do its calculations properly.

Answer (score 3):

Did you inherent this schedule or did you build it? Your parent is also showing actuals entered with 77% complete. This hammock account must have additional packages, some or all of which are at various stages of completion.

Ensure your view does not have a filter on it, eg, show only unfinished or unstarted tasks.

Comment: Ensure your view does not have a filter on it, eg, show only unfinished or unstarted tasks.
==> sure that i don't active any filter.

Answer (score 1):

Did you increase the progress of your child tasks under "Create Ds.." ?

Make sure you don't have any mixed up task dependencies, for instance Start-To-Start. Or any constraints on "Create DS.."

Try removing the dependencies and constraints on "Create DB.." and check if it has calculated accordingly.